# Rails - How to search through has many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models - User, Conversation and UserConversation

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages,  -> { order 'created_at' }, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_conversations, dependent: :destroy
  #if conversation is destroyed all messages and subscriptions will also be  destroyed
  has_many :users, through: :user_conversations
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sent_messages, 
           class_name: 'Message', 
           foreign_key: 'sender_id' 
    has_many :messages, foreign_key: 'recipient_id'

    has_many :user_conversations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :conversations, through: :user_conversations

end
```

```
class UserConversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :conversation

  validates_presence_of :user_id, scope: :conversation_id
end
```

I want to search through conversations of current user and find only conversations where other users name like some value.

```
conversations = @current_user.conversations
conversations = conversations.users.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

But it doesn't work. How to implement it?

Comment: _I want to search through conversations of current user and find only conversations where other users_. Can you explain further that?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I want to search current user conversations by name of other user involved in these conversations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your model Conversation it is an abstraction or it really pretend to be a chat but if you want to find all conversation from the current_user with another user you need your Conversation model to have relations with both users, but the way your relations works are confusing, try with:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # all your previous code

  def find_conversations_by(user_name)
    self.conversations.joins(:user).where("user.name ILIKE ?", "%#{user_name}%") 
  end
end
```

And now, wherever you want to use it write this:

```
current_user.find_conversations_by(a_proof_query_injection_string)
```

By the way, I suggest you to look for another approach.

Comment: Thank you, ```self.conversations.joins(:users).where("users.name ILIKE ?", "%#{user_name}%")``` works fine. I've used this example https://medium.com/@adnama.lin/live-messaging-with-rails-5-action-cable-7f009e0c1d8b. Could you recommend some other approach?

Comment: When you link users to conversations, you should be clear about which end of the conversation they are on, and like to both users in the conversation.  Have two separate foreign keys from `UserConversation` to the `users` table to designate the two users in the conversation.

Comment: I take that back.  I thought conversations could have exactly two users.  Your model is for any number of users in a conversation, so my suggestion is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

```
Conversation.joins(:users)
            .where(users: { id: @current_user })
            .where("users.name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Comment: it should be, but it doesn't work. ```Conversation.joins(:users)
            .where(users: { id: @current_user })``` found  ```ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Conversation id: 20, created_at: "2019-08-27 21:25:49", updated_at: "2019-08-27 21:26:15", has_unread_messages: false, user_id: nil>]``` I am not sure why user_id is nil

Comment: I guess it's happening because current_user is nil.

Comment: @demir The reason it does not work is that you are joining `Conversation` to the `users` table to mean both the users for both ends of the conversation.  The intension is, for a given user, to find all the conversations with another user.  So which end of the conversion the user is, is ambiguous, and your answer does not get the desired results.

Comment: @MarlinPierce I misunderstood the problem: /